# Fedora 27: Getting error repeatedly "Job for <xxx.service> failed because the control process exited with error code"

Tags: linux, fedora

I had installed MySQL using docker some time back it worked until before this error, My laptop switched off due, I rebooted my VM (on Fedora 27) for some reason, I am facing below error, while I was trying to start mysql service. Also I tried to start **`sudo service docker restart`** I get same error. So I am unable to start either docker or mysql server, finally I removed docker installed packages **`sudo dnf remove docker-ce`**, then installed MySQL 5.7 community server referring to [MySQL 5.7 installation guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html)

I do not know whether my Linux OS level anything corrupted???

**`[ravibeli@localdomain ~]$ sudo service mysqld start`**

```
Logs:
[sudo] password for ravibeli: 
Starting mysqld (via systemctl):  Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status mysqld.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

When I run 'journalctl -xe' below error message shown, and unable to fix it? what is the way to fix this issue on VM (Fedora 27)

**`[ravibeli@localdomain ~]$ journalctl  -xe`**

```
May 07 16:06:53 localdomain sudo[6971]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 07 16:06:53 localdomain audit[6971]: USER_START pid=6971 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:sess
May 07 16:06:53 localdomain systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: MySQL database server....
-- Subject: Unit mysqld.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysqld.service has begun starting up.
May 07 16:06:53 localdomain mysqld[8145]: chown: invalid user: ‘mysql:mysql’
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain audit[726]: USER_AVC pid=726 uid=81 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:system_dbusd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='avc: 
                                         exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=81 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain mysqld[8145]: Initializing MySQL database:  2018-05-07T10:36:54.847676Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depre
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain mysqld[8145]: 2018-05-07T10:36:54.851156Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't change to run as user 'mysql' ;  Please check that the user
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain mysqld[8145]: 2018-05-07T10:36:54.851678Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain mysqld[8145]: [FAILED]
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: MySQL database server..
-- Subject: Unit mysqld.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysqld.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=mysqld comm="systemd
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain sudo[6971]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain audit[6971]: USER_END pid=6971 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:sessio
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain audit[6971]: CRED_DISP pid=6971 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcr
lines 1393-1422/1422
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The journal log indicates that the user ***mysql*** might not exist. I can see from the above that you are logged in as user ***ravibeli***.

```
Fatal error: Can't change to run as user 'mysql' ;  Please check that the user
```

To check if the user ***mysql*** exists run the following, it should return a valid user id, if it doesn't then the user doesn't exist and you need to sort that out - most likely a mysqld or Docker configuration problem:

```
id -u mysql
```

If the user does exist, try using **systemctl** to start the service:

```
systemctl start mysqld.service
```

The **mysqld** service has a log file located at `/var/log/mysqld.log`, if none of the above works, this log file may contain more detail about the issue - please add this to your question and we may be able to help you further.

Seeing as you say the user and group do exist, check which user owns the `/var/lib/mysql` folder by running the following command:

```
ls -l /var/lib/mysql
```

If the ***mysql*** user does not own the file, then change the ownership using the following command:

```
chown mysql:mysql -R /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: user and group as mysql exists and `/var/log/mysqld.log` this file has nothing any log, nothing is writing in it.

Comment: I've added a comment to my answer which may help in that case.

Comment: "chown: invalid user: ‘mysql:mysql" makes me think it is an ownership issue, if the user and group does exist.

Comment: You are Mr. Perfect. Running these commands as you suggested `chown mysql:mysql -R /var/lib/mysql` then running `systemctl start mysqld.service` post resolving broker packages using `dnf clean all` then `dnf update` then re-installed MySQL 5.7 server using `dnf install mysql-community-server` resolved the problem

Comment: Great! Glad it helped. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.